# Move files within a ZIP archive

Tags: powershell, zip, 7zip

My Eclipse and Maven development environments are using a different directory structure, such that if I export my results into a JAR / ZIP file, the required directories are included, but at the wrong directory location.

Is there a way, in a PowerShell script on Windows, to move directories within a ZIP file?

If relevant, you may assume that 7-Zip is installed on the system.

Comment: This question has been discussed on meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426511

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a variety of PowerShell modules such as [7Zip4Powershell](https://github.com/thoemmi/7Zip4Powershell) that can help using libraries such as 7-Zip from PowerShell easier.

However, moving a single file inside of a Zip file is easy with just 7-Zip. Here is an example:

```
& "T:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" rn MyWebApp.zip DirOne\SomeClass.jar DirTwo\SomeClass.jar
```

The above command will move *SomeClass.jar* from the *DirOne* directory to the *DirTwo* directory inside of the *MyWebApp.zip*.

Of course if you need to move more than just one file then you could use *7Zip4Powershell* to get a list of file names to move:

```
Install-Module 7Zip4Powershell
Import-Module 7Zip4Powershell

Get-7Zip MyWebApp.zip | ? FileName -match '^DirOne\\' | % {
    & "T:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" rn MyWebApp.zip $_.FileName ($_.Filename -replace "DirOne", "DirTwo")
}
```